# Error message pops up saying "please enter 1 letter"

Tags: tkinter, python-3.5, tkinter-canvas

```
from tkinter import *
from Hangman import *

#GUI for hangman game
class HangmanGui:
    def __init__(self):
        self.game = HangmanGame()
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.title('Hangman')
        makeHangman = self.makeHangman('empty.gif')
        makeHangman.pack() 
        frame2= self.makeframe2()
        frame2.pack() 
        self.root.mainloop()

    def makeHangman(self,filename):
        frame1= Frame(self.root)
        self.img = PhotoImage(file = filename)
        ht = self.img.height()
        wd = self.img.width()
        canvas = Canvas(self.root,
                        height = ht,
                        width = wd
                        )      
        canvas.create_image(0, 0,
                            image = self.img,
                            anchor = NW
                            )
        canvas.pack()
        return frame1

    def makeframe2(self):    
        frame2= Frame(self.root) 
        self.wrong_letter= Label(frame2,
                                 text=self.game.getWrongList)
        self.winner= Label(frame2,
                           text=self.game.win)
        self.correct_answer= Label(frame2,
                                   text=self.showcorrect)
        self.user_input= Entry(frame2, width=10)
        self.button= Button(frame2,
                            text='Guess', command=self.buttonEffect)

        self.wrong_letter.pack()
        self.winner.pack()
        self.correct_answer.pack()
        self.user_input.pack()
        self.button.pack()

        return frame2

    def buttonEffect(self):
        guess=self.user_input.get
        guess1=str(guess)
        if(len(guess1)!=1):
            messagebox.showerror('error','Please only enter 1 letter.')
        #elif(guess1.isalpha()==False):
            #messagebox.showerror('Error', 'Please enter a letter.')

    def showcorrect(self,guess1):
        display = "_" * len(guess1)
        if self.game.chooseword.find(guess1)>=1:
            print()

        wronglist=self.game.getWrongList()
        self.label.config(text=str(wronglist))

        if len(wronglist)== 1:
            makeHangman = self.makeHangman('hangman head.gif')
        elif len(wrongList)== 2:
            makeHangman = self.makeHangman('hangman body.gif')
        elif len(wrongList)== 3:
            makeHangman = self.makeHangman('hangman 1 arm.png')
        elif len(wrongList)== 4:
            makeHangman = self.makeHangman('hangman 2 arms.jpg')
        elif len(wrongList)== 5:
            makeHangman = self.makeHangman('hangman 1 leg.png')
        elif len(wrongList)== 6:
            makeHangman = self.makeHangman('hangman.png')


HangmanGui()
```

Hi, i am trying to make a hangman game using python Tkinter gui, but i am having trouble at the part where the user enters a letter, Whenever i enter a letter, i get a error messagebox popping up saying "Please enter 1 letter" even though i only entered one letter, The part of the code which checks if the user entered 1 letter is under the "Def ButtonEffect" function. I was wondering if anyone could help me out as to why my messagebox is popping up even when i enter 1 letter.

Comment: After pasting code, you must select it and click either the {} button or enter cntl-K.

Comment: This is way too much code to wade through.  It cannot even be run by anyone but you to debug.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.  To debug, include guess and its length in the error message.  Since guess is a string, `guess1 = str(guess)` is useless.  PS: I tried a minimal 10 example and entering 1 char indeed gives a length of 1, and 2 gives 2, and so on, so I have no idea what the problem is.

Comment: The first step should be to do some debugging. For example, printing out the result  of `str(guess)` might have given you enough information to solve the problem on your own.

Comment: Im a noobie in programming help me BaseGod

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this:

```
guess=self.user_input.get
```

You aren't calling the function `get`, you're simply assigning the function to the variable. Later you do `str(guess)` which results in a long string.

To fix this particular problem, add parenthesis to convert the reference to a function call:

```
guess=self.user_input.get()
```

Comment: @bobby: That's unrelated to this question. stackoverflow isn't a code writing service. If you have additional problems, do some research, do some debugging, and then ask another question.

Comment: Be more polite to amateur programmers. And whats the point of stackoverflow

Comment: @bobby: I'm sorry if I offended you. Stackoverflow isn't like other sites that support extended discussions. It's simply not designed for extended discussions. If you have other questions to ask, click the "Ask Question" button and people will be happy to answer. If you bury extra questions in a comment, there's a chance nobody will see it.